# Reset without a reset button

Tags: windows, crash, reset

My Dad just crashed out of a Zoom call. He messaged me:
"Windows crashed... This machine has no external reset button, nor removable battery. Keyboard & mouse seem dead... Looks like Windows kernel crashed. It can't see external keyboard. I plan to open the case and look for a reset key or contacts"

Its an HP Pavilion laptop.

How can he reset it please?

Comment: Can you hold down the power button for 15 seconds? then reboot?

Comment: Thanks Mark but he says it doesn't have a power button

Comment: `he says it doesn't have a power button` -- How does he turn the laptop on then?

Comment: I find it hard to believe the device doesn’t have at least one button which would be necessary to turn the device on.

Comment: sorry, it does have a power button, that worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power button in the HP Pavilion is usually found on the top left.
A long press should turn off the computer,
and then a short press will turn it back on.

This is taken from one HP Pavilion manual:

[image]